# While configuring wso2 ei and ei analytics giving the following exceptions

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

In wso2 EI 6.4 analytics database configuration is not included in the documentation as it invloves stream processor which was not there till 6.3. I'm trying to configure the wso2 ei 6.4 analytics database for ESB profile with postgres database. So,  what are all the databases /schemas required for configuration except `carbon db` like `metrics DB, EI Anlytics db`. And in

```
<wso2_home>/wso2/analytics/conf/dashboard/dbscript
<wso2_home>/wso2/analytics/conf/manager/dbscript
<wso2_home>/wso2/analytics/conf/worker/dbscript
```

Only `metrics script for postgres`  is there, I'm not getting which database/scehma should I create.

Can anyone brief out the steps to be followed for database configuration with POSTGRES DB.

I tried with postgres 9.6 and when I configured databases it is throwing following exceptions, but carbondb is created using postgres 9.6:

```
[2019-01-16 15:17:33,186] ERROR {org.eclipse.equinox.ds} - [SCR] Exception while activating instance org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.StartupListener@2bc03fa1 of component org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.StartupListener  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:915)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.DataBridgeDS.start(DataBridgeDS.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:915)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.idp.client.core.internal.IdPClientServiceComponent.onAllRequiredCapabilitiesAvailable(IdPClientServiceComponent.java:111)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.lambda$notifySatisfiableComponents$7(StartupComponentManager.java:266)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupComponentManager.notifySatisfiableComponents(StartupComponentManager.java:252)
        at org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.startupresolver.StartupOrderResolver$1.run(StartupOrderResolver.java:204)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.exception.DashboardRuntimeException: Cannot create dashboard DAO for DB access.
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.DashboardMetadataProviderImpl.<init>(DashboardMetadataProviderImpl.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.StartupListener.activate(StartupListener.java:111)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.exception.DashboardException: Unable to create the 'DASHBOARD_RESOURCE' table.
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.database.DashboardMetadataDao.createDashboardResourceTable(DashboardMetadataDao.java:84)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.database.DashboardMetadataDao.initDashboardTable(DashboardMetadataDao.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.DashboardMetadataProviderImpl.<init>(DashboardMetadataProviderImpl.java:88)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot find database queries for PostgreSQL 9.6.10.
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.database.QueryManager.getQuery(QueryManager.java:121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.database.QueryManager.getQuery(QueryManager.java:100)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.database.DashboardMetadataDao.createDashboardResourceTable(DashboardMetadataDao.java:77)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.database.query.manager.exception.QueryMappingNotAvailableException: Mapping value for query: 'table_check' not found in Deployment config Map and Component config Map for database type: 'PostgreSQL' and version '9.6.10'.
        at org.wso2.carbon.database.query.manager.QueryProvider.mergeMapping(QueryProvider.java:105)
        at org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.internal.database.QueryManager.getQuery(QueryManager.java:119)
        ... 55 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create empty DB, grant all permissions to wso2 user, update the datasource and run the Analytics?
Some products create the tables at startup as well as in the log provided you have:
*Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core.exception.DashboardException: Unable to create the 'DASHBOARD_RESOURCE' table.*

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, it seems you have started the dashboard profile, what about the worker which does the processing? Were there any issues?

To answer your question, Except metrics DB, all other tables will be created at the startup or when server inserts the first record. Unfortunately, there is a limitation in dashboard runtime with Postgres SQL where we need to introduce the compatible queries in here: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-dashboards/blob/master/components/dashboards/org.wso2.carbon.dashboards.core/src/main/resources/sql-queries.yaml

or else you can give the compatible queries in the wso2ei-6.4.0/conf/dashboard/deployment.yaml as explained in the doc:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Configuring+Database+Queries#ConfiguringDatabaseQueries-DashboardDashboard

Copy the queries with the above structure under the 'wso2.dashboard' namespace.